# How to perform LINQ query over Enum?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, data-binding, enums

Below is my `Enumerator List`:

```
public enum StatusEnum
{
    Open = 1,
    Rejected = 2,
    Accepted = 3,
    Started = 4,
    Completed = 5,
    Cancelled = 6,
    Assigned = 7
}
```

I need to bind this to a `Combobox`, but, only show a few specific statuses and ignore the rest.

**This is what I have so far:**

```
public static List<Activity.StatusEnum> StatusList()
{
        IEnumerable<Activity.StatusEnum> query = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Activity.StatusEnum)).Cast<Activity.StatusEnum>()
                        .Where(x => x == Activity.StatusEnum.Open
                            || x == Activity.StatusEnum.Rejected
                            || x == Activity.StatusEnum.Accepted
                            || x == Activity.StatusEnum.Started);
        return query.ToList();
}
```

However, I feel that the code is little messy and is not a correct approach to bind filtered `Enum` list to a `Combobox`. 
Can anyone suggest a more robust way of doing this?

### Update

I might need to change the Order of selection. So I need a generic solution which doesn't only get the first X number of statuses.

Comment: Is `Activity` a namespace?  You can slim your code down a bit by adding a `using` directive, and removing the `Activity` references.

Comment: You've moved the goalposts. If all you want is (for now) those 4 enum values hardcoded there's nothing terribly wrong with the code you posted - although pswg's is neater. The generic solutions are in the answers, especially mine which sorts the enum values by int (otherwise they sort naturally by unsigned magnitude) and then takes(x) for you. x could easily be an argument to an extension method.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well if you're going to hard code the items that should be in the list anyway, why not just do this:

```
public static List<Activity.StatusEnum> StatusList()
{
    return new List<Activity.StatusEnum>
    { 
        Activity.StatusEnum.Open, 
        Activity.StatusEnum.Rejected, 
        Activity.StatusEnum.Accepted, 
        Activity.StatusEnum.Started 
    };
}
```

You could also dispose of the `List<T>` and just return the array itself. As long as you know these are the items you want, then there's no need for Linq.

Comment: Upvoted, but he should either change the return type into the array type `Activity.StatusEnum[]`, like you suggest, or use collection initializer syntax on the `List<>` (just remove the five charaters `new[]` and the parenthesis `()`). It is crazy to allocate an array that is immediately discarded again (only the `List<>` is kept)!

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Thanks, I'd forgotten about collection initializers.

Answer (score 52):

```
return Enum.GetValues(typeof(Activity.StatusEnum)).Cast<Activity.StatusEnum>().Where((n, x) => x < 4);
```

If you want to be able to change the list of items, just add them into a `List<Activity.StatusEnum>` and use `Contains`:

```
var listValid = new List<Activity.StatusEnum>() { Activity.StatusEnum.Open, Activity.StatusEnum.Rejected, Activity.StatusEnum.Accepted, Activity.StatusEnum.Started };
return Enum.GetValues(typeof(Activity.StatusEnum)).Cast<Activity.StatusEnum>().Where(n => listValid.Contains(n));
```

Comment: I was thinking along these lines, but the use of a magic number bothers me.  Maybe compare to `(int)StatusEnum.Started`?

Comment: @RobertHarvey He said 4, not to compare against Started. It bothers me too, but this does exactly what asked. Unlike the most upvoted answer, too.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion but, I need a solution without Take(4) as the order might change for other situations.

Answer (score 12):

**Steps:**

- Get the `enum` values and cast the results to the type of the `enum`
- Sort the `enum` values by their integer values (otherwise they sort
  naturally by unsigned magnitude)
- Take the first 4

**Code:**

```
return Enum.GetValues(typeof(Activity.StatusEnum))
.Cast<Activity.StatusEnum>()
.OrderBy(se =>(int)se)
.Take(4);
```

**Output:**

> Open  Rejected  Accepted  Started

Answer (score 8):

First, if possible, I'd make your enum values powers of 2, so they could be OR'd together.

```
public enum StatusEnum
{
    Open = 1,
    Rejected = 2,
    Accepted = 4,
    Started = 8,
    Completed = 16,
    Cancelled = 32,
    Assigned = 64
}
```

Then you could do something like this:

```
public static List<Activity.StatusEnum> StatusList()
{
    var statusesToShow = Activity.StatusEnum.Open | Activity.StatusEnum.Rejected | Activity.StatusEnum.Accepted | Activity.StatusEnum.Started;

    return Enum
        .GetValues(typeof(Activity.StatusEnum))
        .Cast<Activity.StatusEnum>()
        .Where(x => (x & statusesToShow) == x)
        .ToList();
}
```

**EDIT**: In light of the fact that you can't change the enum values, I'd just recommend you use something like:

```
public static List<Activity.StatusEnum> StatusList()
{
    return new List<Activity.StatusEnum> {
        Activity.StatusEnum.Open, 
        Activity.StatusEnum.Rejected, 
        Activity.StatusEnum.Accepted, 
        Activity.StatusEnum.Started
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I am using objects which I don't have control over. +1 for solution.

Comment: @Learner: In that case, you don't need to use Enum.GetValues at all, and can just initialize a List<T> with the known enums, which would be much easier. I'd also recommend using an IEnumerable<T> instead of List<T>, unless the binding specifically requires a List<T>.

Comment: May I know the reason for recommending IEnumerable<T>?

Comment: In general, it's considered a best practice to prefer using interfaces over specific implementations. If your code that calls this expects an IEnumerable<T>, it doesn't matter if the function itself uses List<T>, HashSet<T>, T[] (array), or any other implementation. It would only care that there's a number of items it can iterate over. It would also prevent code that called it from calling .Add() on the List<T>. Basically, you just want to give users what they NEED access to, and nothing more. It's probably overkill for this, but it's just generally a good practice.

Comment: BTW, I will wait for Android version of Milestone ;)

Answer (score 6):

> ". . . only show the first 4 statuses and ignore the rest."

To get the first `n` elements of an `IEnumerable<T>`, use the `Take` method:

```
return Enum.GetValues(typeof(Activity.StatusEnum))
    .Cast<Activity.StatusEnum>()
    .Take(4)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Very sorry for the confusion about quoted text. Please see the update. But this will help me. +1

Answer (score 3):

How about something along the lines of:

```
.Where(x => x <= Activity.StatusEnum.Started)
```

Comment: It's a good solution for this scenario, but I might need to change the order in future. Like just show Open, Completed and Assigned.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'd prefer to make a `List` and use `Contains` tbh

Comment: What the heck is `<=` I have not seen that before!? :) Is that meant to be lest or equal or some other linq function I have never seen before?

Comment: @ppumkin it's "less than or equal" operator :)

Comment: So embarrassing:) noob at Linq 3 years ago. :D

Comment: Right, @ppumkin??? - I look at some of my old questions and LOVE to see how far I've come! - Got to absolutely love this community for how much they've helped!!!!

Comment: Completely agreed. So many problems solved, some pages are boookmarked because I keep on forgetting, like complex Grouping with Linq :) But for sure, since Spolsky opened Stack Overflow, the quality of code increased by 66%, globally :)