# Input type into method, Operator "<" cannot be used on type "Type"

Tags: c#, linq, enums

I was trying to make my code cleaner by moving something that I call a lot into a static method. The original code is:

```cs
List<ListItem> listItems = Enum
  .GetValues(typeof(TimelineinfoEnums.StateEnum))
  .Cast<TimelineinfoEnums.StateEnum>()
  .Select(x => new ListItem { 
     Text  = x.ToString(), 
     Value = (int)x })
  .ToList();
```

`TimelineinfoEnums.StateEnum` is just a place holder, the point of my method is to be able to call it, pass in a value, and make `TimelineinfoEnums.StateEnum` some other enum that I'm working with. After reading elsewhere on SO, that you have to use a string input for things like this because the "entity type is literally not known, or knowable, at compile time.", I tried this code:

```cs
 public static List<ListItem> GetDropdownList(string @enum)
 {     
     List<ListItem> listItems = Enum
       .GetValues(@enum.GetType())
       .Cast<@enum.GetType()>()
       .Select(
          x => new ListItem { Text = x.ToString(), Value = (int)x }).ToList();            
          return listItems;
        }
```

However, when I attempted to do so, on the second `@enum.GetType()`I got an error of:

> Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'Type'

I've tried removing the `.GetType()` bit but then I get an error of

> enum is a variable but is used like a type

I'm not too familar with Linq, so I'm likely missing something straightforward, thanks for any help!

**Edit:** `ListItem` Looks like this:

```cs
 public class ListItem
        {
            public int Value { get; set; }
            public string Text { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: casting is some **compiletime**-operation. So there´s no way to do it, when you provide the actual type at **runtime**.

Comment: `.Cast<@enum.GetType()>()` this does not do what you think it does. Generics are a compile-time (meaning: JIT-compile-time) thing, not a runtime thing. The closest think you'll get to that is by using `Activator.CreateInstance`.

Comment: Ok, just to be clear I am providing the value at compile-time.

Comment: @Bubinga No you aren't, you're passing a `string` at runtime.

Comment: Then I guess I don't really know what runtime is. How do you know that I am?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still use generics, but use the `struct, Enum` constraint added in C# 7.3:

Change your code to this:

```
public static List<ListItem> GetDropdownList<TEnum>()
    where TEnum : struct, Enum
{     
     return Enum.GetValues( typeof(TEnum) )
        .Cast<TEnum>()
        .Select( e => new ListItem() { Text = e.ToString(), Value = Convert.ToInt32( e ) } );
        .ToList();

    public static IReadOnlyList<ListItem> Items => _items;
}
```

Note that the above code's performance can be improved by moving it to a *static generic class* and storing the result in a static field, as this will cache the result (as generic types exist once for each type, so there's no need to perform this computation more than once):

```
public static class EnumListItems<TEnum>
    where TEnum : struct, Enum
{
    private static readonly IReadOnlyList<ListItem> _items = Enum.GetValues( typeof(TEnum) )
        .Cast<TEnum>()
        .Select( e => new ListItem() { Text = e.ToString(), Value = Convert.ToInt32( e ) } );
        .ToList();

    public static IReadOnlyList<ListItem> Items => _items;
}
```

Used like so:

```
IReadOnlyList<ListItem> items = EnumListItems<MyEnum>.Items;
```

If you need a mutable list, use `.ToList()`:

```
List<ListItem> items = EnumListItems<MyEnum>.Items.ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for such a thorough answer, ngl I don't fully understand everything though, but that is just because I'm rather new to programming. +1

Comment: @Bubinga I accidentally pressed "Cut" on my code instead of "Copy" when I was expanding my answer. I've restored my original code now. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: How would you change this code to get the display name of the enum values? The ```[Display(Name = "Example")]``` thingo?

Comment: @Bubinga Getting the value of a `DisplayAttribute` for enum members requires a lot of code, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13099834/how-to-get-the-display-name-attribute-of-an-enum-member-via-mvc-razor-code

Answer (score 1):

> entity type is literally not known, or knowable, at compile time

You [appear to have to use `Cast<T>()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17091917/how-to-perform-linq-query-over-enum) to do [anything meaningful with Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167361/how-do-i-convert-an-enum-to-a-list-in-c), because `Enum.GetValues()`'s return type was never updated to support generic collections for Linq. Also, `@enum.GetType()` will always return `System.String`.

The only thing you want to extract, are the enum members' integer and textual value, and you can extract those from *any* enum. So:

```
private static List<ListItem> GetListItems<TEnum>()
{
    var result = new List<ListItem>();
    
    foreach (object e in Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum)))
    {
        result.Add(new ListItem 
        { 
            Text = e.ToString(),
            Value = (int)e
        });
    }
               
    return result;
}
```

When using [C# 7.3 and up, you should constrain `TEnum` to `System.Enum`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/dissecting-new-generics-constraints-in-c-7-3/). And if you want Linq instead of a loop, you can use `Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum)).Cast<System.Enum>()`.

Now if you don't know `TEnum` at compile time, look at [How to call generic method with a given Type object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408120/how-to-call-generic-method-with-a-given-type-object) and `Type.GetType(enumName)`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but it's giving me an error at ```(int)e``` saying that it, "Cannot convert type 'System.Enum' to 'int'"

Comment: Yeah that needed to be an `object`, not `Enum`, see edit.